# get # of rows and # of columns of a square matrix from vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, sqrt

I have a vector of size lets say 4:

```
vector <double> example;
example.push_back(3.0); 
example.push_back(10.1);
example.push_back(33.1);
example.push_back(23.3);
```

so I have [3 10.1 33.1 23.3];

If I know I have a square matrix (i.e. sizes can only be 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49...)

How do I know the # of rows which is the same as the number of columns in c++??

so I am doing

```
int size, col, row;
size = example.size();

row = col = sqrt(size);
```

Is there other a faster way??

Comment: well, if I have a lot of elements....maybe I am asking something that is not possible, I mean, use a vector function, or something...

Comment: If you have a lot of elements, this won't get much slower. `size()` is guaranteed constant-time.

Comment: Wikipedia has a bunch of methods listed; you can try them all out. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots Do let us know if you find out which one the fastest is :)

Comment: Don't worry so much about optimizing something which is only done once at initialization. The `sqrt` function expresses exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is the fastest way of doing it. Both of these operations are quite fast. I don't see a situation in which these operations would be the bottleneck of your program. If your program is slow, feel free to post that code if you need it to be faster.

Comment: Alright thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two-dimensional array allocated as contiguous locations will be faster than a `vector` of `vector`s or an array of `vector`s.  A vector has a slight disadvantage in that functions must be called to access the vector (although the compiler may optimize these out).

For example:

```
enum {MATRIX_SIZE = 4};

// Define a square matrix of integers
int matrix[MATRIX_SIZE * MATRIX_SIZE];

// Set value at row: 3, column 2 to 64:
unsigned int row = 3;
unsigned int column = 2;
matrix[row * MATRIX_SIZE + column] = 64;
```

Using vectors has a slight overhead.

**The question to answer is whether the difference in performance between arrays and vectors is worthwhile.**  The person hours in maintenance and development may outweigh the benefit in performance (i.e. a slower but correct and released applications may be worth more than a faster application that is released much later to the market place or consumers).

Comment: "A vector has a slight disadvantage in that functions must be called to access the vector" Huh? Nah. It's true there will be a pointer dereference but this is usually completely negligible.  [Contrary to popular nonsense, basic operations on vectors don't have to be slower than equivalent operations on arrays/pointers.](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/vector-speed.cpp)

Comment: @Tomalak, the one time I tested indexing into a vector against indexing off a pointer, the pointer came out ahead. But this was back with VC6, I'm sure things have improved since then...

Comment: Also your suggestion only works if your sizes are fixed at compile-time; and I'd recommend `std::array` anyway. There is no need to use raw arrays here.

Comment: @Mark: VC++6 cannot be considered to be a C++ compiler!

Comment: @Tomalak:  There *may* be overhead in calling functions to access vector elements or to validate indicies.  In either case, the execution time for these functions is probably negligible in most cases.  Profiling will present the truth.

Comment: @Thomas: But you don't have to use functions to access vector elements, or validate indices. And, when you do anyway, comparisons to arrays (which do not have these additional features) are meaningless!